# script or jquery on detect html text and display div on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two `DIV`'s. One is named as `<div id="Women">` and another`<div id="Men">`. When the page is loaded it detects if the label name is WOMEN to show the div of Women. However, something is wrong in my script

```
<asp:Label ID="GenderShow" runat="server"  CssClass="showitem"></asp:Label>
$(function () {
    var genderToShow = $("#GenderShow").text();
    if ($(genderToShow).next().html() == 'Women') {
        $('#Women').show();
        $('#Man').hide();
    }
   else if ($(genderToShow).next().html() == 'Men') {
        $('#Women').hide();
        $('#Man').show();    
    }
});
```

Comment: first things first you are missing # symbol here if (('GenderShow')

Comment: can you post your full html structure?? I mean where these <div id="Women"> and <div id="Men"> placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  in Div tag as show below

**`<div id='GenderContain'><asp:Label ID="GenderShow" runat="server"  CssClass="showitem"></asp:Label></div>`**

$(function () {
    var genderToShow = $("#GenderContain span").html(); 
    if (genderToShow.indexOf('Women')) {
       
 $('#Women').show();
        
$('#Man').hide();
    }
   else if (genderToShow.indexOf('Men')) {
       
 $('#Women').hide();
       
 $('#Man').show();
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

not to mention keep that in script tags. also check whether you have referred jquery.js or not

```
$(function () {
        var genderToShow = $("#GenderShow").text();
        if (genderToShow=="Women") {
            $('#Women').show();
            $('#Man').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('#Women').hide();
            $('#Man').show();
        }
    });




<form id="form1" runat="server">


    <asp:Label ID="GenderShow" runat="server" Text="Men"></asp:Label>

    <div id="Women" class="category" onclick="ChangeValidatorW(this);">

        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbWomen" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="wTopWear">WOMEN TOP WEAR</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="wOutherWear">WOMEN OUTHERWEAR</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="wBottomWear">WOMEN BOTTOM WEAR</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>

    </div>


    <div id="Man" class="category" onclick="ChangeValidatorM(this);">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbMen" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="mTopWear">MEN TOP WEAR</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="mOutherWear">MEN OUTHERWEAR</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="mBottomWear">MEN BOTTOM WEAR</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function () {
               var genderToShow = $("#GenderShow").text();
               if (genderToShow == 'Women') {
                   $('#Women').show();
                   $('#Man').hide();

               }
               else if (genderToShow == 'Men') {
                   $('#Women').hide();
                   $('#Man').show();

               }
           });
```

Hope it helps